# What is the default SQL result sort order with 'select *'?

Tags: sql, oracle

If I perform a `select * from mytable`, in which order will the records get displayed? Will it take the first column or order it by some sort of meta data?

I am using an Oracle Database.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is ***NO*** default "sort" order. Rows in a relational table **are not sorted**.

The only (really: the only) way to get a specific order is to use an `ORDER BY`

Whatever order you see when running a `SELECT` without `ORDER BY` is **pure coincident** and can change with the next execution.

The order can change because of various reasons:

- other sessions are running the same statement
- the table was updated
- the execution plan changes
- ...

Here is a little SQLFiddle that shows you how the "order" can change: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19d14/2

Note that the initial "order" is not even the same as the insertion order!

Comment: It can change? I actually never saw a change on the first few records, they are always the same..?

Comment: @FlorianMüller - every day, on my drive to work, I see a blue car, followed by a red car, followed by a green car. Does that, for some reason, entitle me to expect that this must *always* happen? Or is it just a coincidence and not something I should rely on always being true?

Comment: @FlorianMüller: see my SQLFiddle example.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: If you *really* and *every day* see a blue car followed by a red car followed by a green car then I actually don't think this is a coincidence. Must it *always* happen? Who knows? Until you know *why* you observe this odd pattern of colors on your drive to work you cannot say with certainity that it must change.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger unless you know why you observe the pattern of colours then you have no basis to believe anything.

Comment: Of course typically what you'd see is the rows returned in the order by which the database identified them as part of the result set, with the caveat that in parallel query they have to be sent from query slaves to the query coordinator in batches according to the row and message size. So you might observe ordering, particularly if the table was loaded with a direct path insert from an ordered query, but you can never rely on that. Excellent demo, btw.

Comment: Oh also a GROUP BY is sometimes said to perform an ORDER BY, but that is dependent on the GROUP BY algorithm used, which can not be relied on to stay constant, and does not respect linguistic sort.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: this is exactly why the example with the car-colors does not explain why Florian observed the same order with his query. With SQL/Oracle, we know why we observe this pattern, and why we can't rely on it being repeated.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger are you making a point about the unreliability of car colour ordering, or Oracle row ordering? :)

Comment: @FlorianMüller: the order of the first few rows can change when you update them. Unless you've been merge joining or hash joining sets, the default order basically is the order in which the physical rows are read -- and the latter is susceptible to change when rows are updated.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: I was trying to point out that the cars don't prove that Oracle doesn't change the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, there is **NO** sort order unless specified.

This can vary from storing, indexing, index storing, index selection, execution plan, database engine implementation, willy nilly like I feel.

So as you can see, you either specify a sort order, or you dont count on it.

Comment: But how comes that the selected records do have the same order every time I execute this statement?